# How to do CRUD operations in google chrome extension?

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can anybody help me by showing en example code or tutorial about how to do CRUD operations in Google Chrome Extension development by using MYSQL as the database.
I searched it for 2 days, as I am a novice programmer I couldn't get the whole idea by reading https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted stuff in here. Please can any body suggest a good tutorial for all create retrieve delete and update operations to me to have the basic idea even

Comment: try to create a Rest web service and use that api from chrome extension for CRUD operations.

Comment: Chrome can't run mysql so you can only use WebSQL storage (Chrome-only) or connect to an external host (or localhost) via XMLHttpRequest or fetch, there are lots of examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you sir, You mean through an XMLHttpRequest I can perform CRUD operations with MYSQL. Am i right?

Comment: Not directly. You'll need to set up a separate server and connect to it.

Comment: @KetanModi Rest web service is in Java. Can i find a way to do that in web languages such as javascript or php

Comment: The service language is irrelevant. Find a tutorial on using REST from js.